# Mysql: Store dynamically number of dates?

Tags: mysql

Using jQuery I'we made a form that expands fields for a date input. The user can add a date, and populate it with a registration deadline for his sport-event. He can make a maximum of 10 deadlines. So some events have like 4 deadlines and some 7.

What would be the best practice to store that data? I know i need a new table only for that but how would i organize that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply have a table events:

```
events
------
ID
event_name
created_by_user
```

and a table deadlines:

```
deadlines
---------
event_id (foreign key to events.ID)
deadline_number (an increasing value to distinguish and order the deadlines per event)
deadline_date
```

Then you would have another table like this:

```
event_deadline_limiter
--------------------
deadline
```

This table would hold just the numbers from 1 to 10. The deadline_number from the deadlines table would also have a foreign key to this table. Therefore an error would be raised when the user tries to insert more than 10 deadlines.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking about a similar solution but i was afraid that the deadlines table would become to bulky. I think i wont need the event_deadline_limiter because i already got a limitation in the jQuery.